wireless mouse keeps losing connection
I have a Windows 10 Lenovo laptop PC (fully updated) and a simple wireless mouse.
Recently, I've noticed that every few seconds, it simply gets "stuck" and doesn't respond for 2-3 seconds (with no indication or messages why and when), then reacts again.
Of course, the first thing I've checked is the battery, and also tried to connect the USB dongle in all available slots.
I happen to have a few mice from the same kind and brand, and it happens the same with each of them.
So, right now my conclusion is that the problem is not with the mouse, and not with the USB connection to the laptop.
My suspicion right now is that something from the OS gets the connection to the moust disconnected from it every few seconds, for some reason.
How can I check that? Has anyone encountered such an issue before?

Are you in an environment with lots of RF interference?

do you have access to a different laptop? or give that mouse to someone else to confirm it is an OS issue ? Also, these mouses goto sleep on inactivity to save on-device battery. Could be that this is not calibrated well and the mouse is basically going into "sleep" mode after shorter periods of inactivity?
Try something to force the mouse to keep "moving" and active and see if the OS forces it to disconnect regadless?

Possibly that it is connected into or too near to a USB3.0 port & the connection is being corrupted due to interference problems. I had mine hanging of a short extension lead before it would work reliably.
